# whats the difference between Developer and MSbuild Command prompt

Tags: c#

whats the difference between  Developer and MSbuild Command prompt?which one do you use for general purpose application building?does it matter on which to use and how?

[image: Commandline utilities]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To put simply, the difference is what commands are available. For the most part, though, you can consider the Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt as being a super-set to the MSBuild command prompt. The Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt just adds additional settings such as adjusts `%PATH%` to include Visual Studio tooling, performance tools, TypeScript compiler, runs dnvm setup, and a few other things.

If you're really curious, have a look in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools` directory for `VsMSBuildCmd.bat` and `VsDevCmd.bat`.

Comment: When you said `VS Command Prompt as being a super-set to the MSBuild command prompt ` did you mean Developer Command Prompt?

Comment: `VsMSBuildCmd.bat` has some functionality for clearing variables from calls to other scripts. Specifically it unsets a number of variables set by `VCVarsQueryRegistry.bat`. Besides that functionality, they have no clashing lines, calls, or variable-setting. `VsDevCmd.bat` just handles more than `VsMSBuildCmd.bat` does on its own. Since they exist in the same directory, you may want to do a simple file-comparison with any number of file-comparing tools to see what precisely is different.